# select_best: yet another partitioning algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

The title is somewhat a misnomer; my apologies. The goal of the procedure is to partition a range of `first, last` by `mid` for the postcondition

```
max(first, mid) <= min(mid, last)
```

The actual code (`best_n.h`):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

#if !defined(BidirectionalIterator)
#define BidirectionalIterator typename
#endif

template <BidirectionalIterator I>
void select_best(I first, I mid, I last) {
    using T = typename I::value_type;
    while (first != mid) {
        T pivot = *first;
        I pp = std::partition(first, last, [pivot](T elt) { return elt < pivot; });
        if (pp == first) std::advance(pp, 1);
        if (std::distance(first, pp) > std::distance(first, mid)) last = pp;
        else                                                      first = pp;
    }
}
```

Works fine if I didn't mistype anything.

Questions:

- Seeking overall improvements.
- What is a right name?
- Currently `void`. Is there anything useful to return?
- I don't like passing lambda to `std::partition`. Any suggestions to avoid it?
- A performance is weird. Regardless of a pivot selection strategy, an execution time stays pretty much constant as a function of `mid`. Obviously outperforms `std::partial_sort` for somewhat sizable initial ranges, but loses badly for short ones. Any suggestions?

PS: I have benchmarks if anybody's interested.

PPS: I am well aware of the beautiful [best 2](https://github.com/rjernst/stepanov-components-course/blob/master/code/lecture11/) Stepanov's approach. Challenging everybody to generalize it.

Comment: As I understand the algorithm the output is not sorted, it is only guaranteed to have the best n elements in some arbitrary order in the first n positions of the range. A fair comparison should therefore be against [`std::nth_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) instead of `std::partial_sort`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of points on the style rather than the algorithm itself.

First, I find the `#ifdef` for the typename peculiar, it detracts from clarity, and is a pointless use of macros, it may be fine for a small snippet but in a large project or a library header such a thing can wreak havoc. Consider simply,

```
template <class BidirectionalIterator>
```

That said, note that C++11 relaxes `std::partition` to a ForwardIterator, so I would simply say,

```
template <class ForwardIterator>
void select_best(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator mid, ForwardIterator last);
```

The type `T` is also a bad choice to denote a `value_type`, it has too much baggage as a template parameter. Simply say,

```
using value_type = typename I::value_type;
```

Then consider avoiding the inadvertent copy of the value by changing the code to take a const reference of the pivot,

```
const T& pivot = *first;
```

The lambdas are arguably the preferred way to write the predicate (let's not venture into `std::bind` and `std::min` territory), but again I would capture the value by a reference to avoid a copy, and be less verbose,

```
[&](const T& elt) { return elt < pivot; }
```

Consider either using brackets with if-else clauses or at least put the conditional statement on a separate line.

```
if ( ... )
    statement;
else
```

note that using `std::distance` implies that complexity of your function can blow up to `O(n)` for that use only (where `n` is the `pp`, somewhere around `N/2`), and if you want `O(1)` for the distance calculation you have to make sure your iterators are random access.

and last, please get rid of the ghastly space in `else first = pp;`.

For your question on the return value, would it be useful to return `pp` itself?